# Google Analytics for Firebase and Google Analytics v4

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I’m currently working on an Android application that uses Google Analytics V4 for analysis. This has been working well for a couple of years now and the app reports are available in the dashboard in the Google Analytics interface.

I’m now migrating to Firebase SDK for analytics. I don’t want to lose the data I currently have in the Google Analytics interface.

As per the official documentation here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/android/, if I use Firebase SDK for analytics, once the data is captured, it's available in a dashboard in both the Google Analytics interface and the Firebase console.

But I’m confused because I also read in another post that we have to integrate with Google Tag Manager to make data available in both Google Analytics interface and the Firebase console.
[Android - Google tag Manager with Google Analytics and Firebase Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125623/android-google-tag-manager-with-google-analytics-and-firebase-analytics)

My questions are:

1)  If I switch to Firebase SDK, will my app reports be automatically available on both Google Analytics interface and Firebase console?

2)  Do I need to integrate with Google Tag Manager to make data available on both interfaces?

3)  If I send custom events using Firebase SDK as follows,

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString(CATEGORY_KEY, "test");
params.putString(ACTION_KEY, event);
params.putString(LABEL_KEY, label);
params.putLong(VALUE_KEY, duration);
mAnalytics.logEvent(EVENT_KEY, params);
```

will it appear in the Google Analytics interface?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, the Google Analytics for Firebase dashboard is in both the Google Analytics interface and the Firebase console.
2. You need to use GTM if you are sending events to an existing GA property - e.g. you want to see a single report with web and mobile.
3. Google Analytics for Firebase dashboard, which is in both interfaces.